# Are FCM tokens specific to an App or a Device?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm confused as to whether an FCM token is specific to a device, or a *specific app on a device*.  In much of the documentation I've read on the subject, it says that an FCM token is used to "target a specific device", but does this mean that when that token is used, every app on the device can receive the notification?  Or just the app that requested the token in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a token for app (uniq from firebase configs) and device.
For example if you create 2 app with two different firebase configs but you request the token from the same device, the service will give you two different tokens.

To be clear: when Firebase documentation uses the term "device", it frequently means "app instance [on a device]".  Therefore, the following documentation:

> Register devices to receive messages from FCM. An instance of a client app registers to receive messages, obtaining a registration token that uniquely identifies the app instance.

... would more accurately be stated:

> Register app instances to receive messages from FCM. An instance of a client app registers to receive messages, obtaining a registration token that uniquely identifies the app instance.

This also applies to much other mobile notifications documentation, including Microsoft's Notification Hubs documentation.

Comment: OK, so the Firebase documentation is just really confusing, then?  Here's a direct quote from it: `Register devices to receive messages from FCM. An instance of a client app registers to receive messages, obtaining a registration token that uniquely identifies the app instance.`  They literally use "device" in one sentence and then "client app" in the next, as if they were interchangeable!  Arghh!

Comment: Yeah maybe not the best way to explain that.
I had plenty application installed with firebase FCM from the same device and even from the same project (but different "app") and they have different tokens.

Comment: You can have a single Firebase project that has many app ids "apps" inside. For example to manage different app flavors under the same project. Each app when requesting the device token will generate diferente device tokens. This is also handy to you be able to target different "apps" for a push notification for example. So, during token registration, you should send the device and your "app id" to database to be able to target each separately